# How to list the ipaddress of hosts in a network?

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

I am using the educational institute internet service using Wifi as well as wired LAN.

The basic setup what i understand is that whole institute is covered with wifi and there are multiple wifi access point with different names. There is a dedicated wired lan service in each of the dorms and departments(They are multiple). I donot know how the internal network is setup?

Every host is connected to outside internet access through proxy servers.

What i want is that how i can list each and every hosts connected(name, ipaddress) in all the dorm and departments to different wifi routers as well as the Wired LAN using any of wlan or wired lan?

The internal ip's in my network is 10.xxx.xxx.xxx.
How nbtscan helps in this regard?

NOTE : I want to do this using linux. I am little bit new to these networking concepts. So apologies for any ambiguous question. Please do correct such text.

Comment: But those thread donot answer my query so i have raised this one...

Answer (score 1):

I would use `nmap` to scan for all hosts:

```
$ nmap -sP 10.xxx.xxx.0/24
```

, where `10.xxx.xxx.0/24` is a subnet mask, which in your case will be around 20-22, or `nbtscan` for NetBIOS hosts:

```
$ nbtscan 10.xxx.xxx.0/24
```

Comment: current scenrio with me is that when i am using wired lan at one of the dorm and local ips are assigned as 10.103.XXX.XXX for that dorm. So when i use nmap the output is as follows: 

Nmap scan report for 10.103.8.2
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
It doesn't list hostname. Also nbtscan only list the netbios of the host connected in that dorm, not in another dorm assigned say 10.104.xxx.xxx
ips. How to list all the host connected in whole institute network locally?